# If A is decidable, is A* decidable?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

my thought process is that since you can construct a Turing machine that decides the language, all you would need to do is construct it so that it continues to accept every time the same valid strings are inputted, but i'm not sure if that's right/how to provide a proper explanation for it.

pseudocode of my understanding:

```
function PartitionA(s: string, A: set of strings) -> boolean:
n = length(s)

partition = array of size n, initialized to false

# Base case: empty string can always be partitioned into strings in A
partition[0] = true

for i from 1 to n:
    for j from 0 to i:
        # Check if the substring s[j:i] belongs to set A
        if partition[j] is true and A.contains(s[j:i]):
            partition[i] = true
            break

#  last element of array shows if entire string can be partitioned
return partition[n - 1]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof of the equivalence of regular expressions and finite automata (say, languages recognizable by a DFA)?

Comment: The answer is yes, as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language#Closure_properties). I'm not totally convinced by your explanation - I think a clearer one is "given a program to check if a string belongs to $A$, it is possible to build a program that, given a string, checks if it can be partitioned into strings in $A$". Can you see why that's true?

Comment: somewhat i think, basically that regular expressions and FAs have equivalent power; you can prove this by first constructing each part of the definition for an RE (proving that a language described by a regular expression is regular), then remove states from an FA and reconstruct it to convert it into a regular expression (proving that if a language is regular, a regular expression can describe it)

Comment: Hello @anomaly. I am not sure I understand your comment. Was it intended as a hint that's directly helpful in this question?

Comment: To answer Izaak (sorry, not sure how if i can @ people), I think so- let me know if my psuedocode makes sense (i will update my answer)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: Yes, the construction of the star closure in that proof is the same construction as in this case. (Also, unrelatedly, I like your user icon.)

Comment: @anomaly, thank you :D. I realise now that your hint actually makes total sense - please excuse me. (I always think of this proof in a "deterministic" way, but of course a "nondeterministic" argument works just as well and is arguably nicer).

Comment: OP, your pseudocode looks sensible to me! Nice work. If anything, there was no need to be this clever about it. It would work just as well to completely "turn your brain off" and write a program that loops over every possible partition and checks if it consists of words from $A$. You may also like to visit [this thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19811/76272).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: No worries, nothing whatsoever to apologize for.